# TLS error by connecting to API with OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I get an error while tring to connect to an APi server with OkHttpClient
made full of reaserch about it and tryed any option that can maybe help

I am working with Eclipse
my error was **"connection closed by peer"** and I couldnt resolve it so I downloded jar files of OkHttp and then I det the error:

```
Unable to find acceptable protocols. isFallback=false, modes=[ConnectionSpec(cipherSuites=[TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA], tlsVersions=[TLS_1_2], supportsTlsExtensions=true)], supported protocols=[SSLv3, TLSv1]
```

....

```
String r = "";
Response response;
try {
String url = "https://api.honeywell.com/oauth2/token";
        RequestBody requestBody = new 
    MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML").build();

Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS).tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                .cipherSuites(CipherSuite.TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA).build();

        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec)).build();

        try {
            response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            r = response.body().toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            r = "1111 " + e.getMessage();
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        r = "222 " + e.getMessage();
    }

    return r;
```

can anyone help me How to set up the ConnectioSpecs? I think this is my issue what ecver I put over there I get an error with what I put.

Thank you for looking into my problem because I am lost.